# Is it possible to temporarily disable notifications?

Tags: 12.04, unity, notification

I certainly like notifications in 12.04, but depending on the work I do they can be quite distracting.

Is there an official way or a tweak to temporarily deactivate notifications?

UPDATE:
To clearify, I am looking for a way to do that in Unity.

Comment: this is a wishlist bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/461058

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a "don't disturb" option to temporarily hide notifications, like on macbooks?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/769948/is-there-a-dont-disturb-option-to-temporarily-hide-notifications-like-on-mac)

Comment: Best solution tested on ubuntu 18.04.
https://github.com/pop-os/gnome-shell-extension-do-not-disturb

Answer (score 5):

This is how I achieved it

Create a sh file called `stopNotification.sh` and paste this line

```
killall -s SIGSTOP notify-osd
```

Create another sh file and `continueNotification.sh` and paste following line

```
killall -s SIGCONT notify-osd
```

Then goto `system settings` > `keyboard` and assign a shortcut for it.

Simple :)

Comment: Thank you for your great solution! I allowed myself to put it on [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/orschiro/46d75fce983ebf4f5d9aa199cd781606).

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that when I continue them again, I get all the lost notifications back, and this takes hours if I have had them off for, say, a whole backup process...

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's an official way, but it's easy enough to disable in the terminal (for presentations, etc.):

```
  sudo chmod 000 /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd
  killall notify-osd
```

Afterward, just `chmod` it back to 755 and notifications will resume.

Relevant: http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/25512/

Comment: You need root access to do this. That's not very practical.

Answer (score 3):

Use NoNotification and use don't disturb mode :)

https://launchpad.net/nonotifs

You can save lost notifications to check them later.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vlijm/nonotifs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nonotifs
```

[NoNotification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApJys.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable popup notifications (the bubbles) graphically.
Open `System Monitor`, find the process named `notify-osd`, right click on it and select stop; if you want notifications back, right click again on the process and click continue.

Notes.

1. You can test if it's working trying to change audio level from keyboard.
2. Be sure that there aren't bubbles opened when you stop `notify-osd`, otherwise they remain locked there.
3. I don't know why, but when `notify-osd` is disabled, shortcuts doesn't work well; I mean, all shortcuts (even Ctrl+Alt+L for example). This doesn't always happen and is particularly evident when you use keyboard  shortcuts for audio (e.g. to mute, increase or decrease volume, but also to pause or change the music).

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

simply disable process `notify-osd` from system monitor

**Stop Process**     : To stop popping up notifications

**Continue Process** : To continue popping up notifications

Comment: how is this different to the answer provided by tigerjack89 40 minutes earlier?

Comment: I had already typed answer but I had to switch tab and till the time his answer was not there. After sometime when I switched back to this tab then posted my reply.