# Is there a "don't disturb" option to temporarily hide notifications, like on macbooks?

Tags: scripts, indicator, notification, notify-osd, notify-send

Does there exist "Don't disturb mode" as is does for OSX device, where you can decided when notification can bother you, or not..

I just installed chrome, and I usually get spammed by group texts and other notification, which can be annoying when I try work.. On my macbook I have the option to turn on "Do no disturb" which mutes all form of notication.. Does something like that exist for Ubuntu?

Comment: There is an option for firefox, but I'm no chrome user so can't tell about that

Comment: The problem isn't chrome specific, but notifications in general..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I temporarily "mute" all notification-bubbles coming from one or more sources?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/252036/how-can-i-temporarily-mute-all-notification-bubbles-coming-from-one-or-more-so)

Comment: Have developed a script . So far it's on my github : https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/notify-block.sh  I will update my answer as soon as i have time today. Will also include a nice shortcut that you can pin to the launcher

Comment: Answer edited, please review. Let me know if there's additional features that you want  me to add

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I customize/disable notification bubbles?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13464/how-can-i-customize-disable-notification-bubbles)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### 1. Major update

Just finished a completely rewritten version of the indicator (0.9.0). Options now include:

- suppressing only notifications, containing specific strings
- suppressing (muting) sound
- logging missed notifications
- running on startup
- remembering the last state (suppressing or not) on next run

Furthermore many, many improvements on interface and behaviour.

[image] [image]

Installing is unchanged (ppa):

```
sudo apt-add-repository  ppa:vlijm/nonotifs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nonotifs
```

---

### 2. Old(er) answer

#### Indicator to mute/show notifications

With the indicator below, you can choose to temporarily switch off notifications:

[image]

or show notifications:

[image]

#### How it works

The trick is a simple command, using `dbus-monitor` to intercept upcoming notifications and stop them before they appear.
The indicator is a user-friendly "wrapper" to toggle it off and on.

#### How to set up

---

As per *now* (*for Trusty, Vivid, Wily, Xenial*):

```
sudo apt-add-repository  ppa:vlijm/nonotifs
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nonotifs
```

This will install globally (including the launcher). Installing via ppa is preferred, since it maintains the latest version, and is regularly updated. 
The indicator will appear in Dash as **NoNotifications**

If you install by the ppa, but previously installed manually from below, please run `rm ~/.local/share/applications/nonotif.desktop` first to remove the local `.desktop` file.

---

*Or manually:*

The solution exists of a number of items you simply need to store together in one and the same directory.

1. Create a directory or folder (can be anywhere in your home directory e.g.)
2. The indicator:
   Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `nonotif_indicator.py`:

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import os
   import signal
   import gi
   import subprocess
   gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
   gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
   from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3

   currpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
   proc = "nonotifs.sh"

   def run(path):
       try: 
           pid = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "-f", proc]).decode("utf-8").strip()
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           subprocess.Popen(path+"/"+proc)

   def show():
       try:
           pid = subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "-f", proc]).decode("utf-8").strip()
           subprocess.Popen(["pkill", "-P", pid])
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           pass

   class Indicator():
       def __init__(self):
           self.app = 'nonotif'
           iconpath = currpath+"/grey.png"
           self.testindicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
               self.app, iconpath,
               AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
           self.testindicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
           self.testindicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())

       def create_menu(self):
           menu = Gtk.Menu()
           item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
           item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
           item_silent = Gtk.MenuItem("Don't disturb")
           item_silent.connect('activate', self.silent)
           item_show = Gtk.MenuItem("Show notifications")
           item_show.connect('activate', self.show)
           menu.append(item_quit)
           menu.append(item_silent)
           menu.append(item_show)
           menu.show_all()
           return menu

       def stop(self, source):
           Gtk.main_quit()

       def silent(self, source):
           self.testindicator.set_icon(currpath+"/red.png")
           run(currpath)

       def show(self, source):
           self.testindicator.set_icon(currpath+"/green.png")
           show()

   Indicator()
   signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
   Gtk.main()
   ```
3. The `dbus-monitor` script; save it (exactly) as `nonotifs.sh` ***in one and the same directory*** as the first script:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" | xargs -I '{}' pkill notify-osd
   ```

   ***Make this script executable***
4. Three icons; right-click on each of them and save them together with the two scripts as (exactly):

   [image] <-- `green.png`

   [image] <-- `red.png`

   [image]<-- `grey.png`
5. That's it. Now test-run the indicator with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/nonotif_indicator.py
   ```

   and switch notifications on/of

#### Launcher

In case you'd like a launcher with the indicator:

[image]

- Copy the icon below, save it as `nonotificon.png`:

  [image]
- Copy the code below into an empty file:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Name=No Notifications
  Exec=python3 /path/to/nonotif_indicator.py
  Icon=/path/to/nonotificon.png
  Type=Application
  ```
- Edit the lines:

  ```
  Exec=python3 /path/to/nonotif_indicator.py
  ```

  and

  ```
  Icon=/path/to/nonotificon.png
  ```

  according to the actual paths, and save the file as `nonotif.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications`

#### Add the indicator to Startup Applications

You can add the indicator to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Add the command:

```
/bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/nonotif_indicator.py"
```

Comment: You're amazing!  :-)

Comment: He @Fabby so great to see you around!

Comment: Yet another great script, Jacob! Idea: Can the script also block audio notifications that go along with the notify-osd ones?

Comment: @orschiro thanks! Are those notify-osd notifications too? Not sure what notifications you are referring to.

Comment: Example: Upon receiving a new email, my email client [Nylas N1](https://github.com/nylas/N1) displays the visual osd-notification with an accompanying popping-up sound. This is annoying in moments when you're listening to something else, do an audio recording, etc. Is that more clear?

Comment: @JacobVlijm how about toggling the status by a simple click on the top bar icon? The context menu then only needs the `quit` option to terminate the indicator. This would further simplify the indicator. :-)

Comment: @JacobVlijm what do you think of a [startup parameter](http://i.imgur.com/7YNYFnc.png)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm toggle between green and red by clicking with the left mouse button on the icon?

Comment: @RobertOrzanna Coincidentally, I am refreshing this one, extending possibilities. I will look into it :)

Comment: @RobertOrzanna ...but I am not sure, left click calls the menu by default.

Comment: @JacobVlijm great! Why would you need "grey"? Either you show notifications or you block them. Thus toggling between two states with a simple mouse click.

Comment: @RobertOrzanna that is one of the things that is changed in version 1.0 :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm cool! :-)

Comment: Hi @RobertOrzanna see the rewritten version (now 0.9.2).

Comment: @JacobVlijm what a great release! :-)

Answer (score 11):

#### Introduction

The script bellow allows muting any notifications from appearing on screen. There are two basic options `-m` for mute and `-u` for unmute.  Both are put together into a `.desktop` file to serve as a launcher.

When `-m` is used, the notify-osd will send a final notification before being blocked. If there is another instance of script running, it will show a graphical popup that will inform a user that the script is already doing its job.

When called with `-u` option, the script will stop blocking notifications and will confirm that by showing one. If no previous instance of script is running, the user will be notified that nothing is blocked right now.

#### Script Source

The script source is available here. For more up-to-date version you can always find it on my [github](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep). You can install git with `sudo apt-get install git` and clone the whole repository with `git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep.git` or use

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SergKolo/sergrep/master/notify-block.sh  && chmod +x notify-block.sh
```

to get just the script itself.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
###########################################################
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com 
# Date: May 10th 2016
# Purpose: Notification blocker for Ubuntu
# Written for: 
# Tested on:  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
###########################################################
# Copyright: Serg Kolo ,2016 
#    
#     Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is hereby granted
#     without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
#     appear in all copies.
#
#     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
#     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
#     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL
#     THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
#     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
#     FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER
#     DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.

ARGV0="$0"
ARGC=$#

mute_notifications()
{ 

  self=${ARGV0##*/}
  CHECK_PID_NUMS=$(pgrep -f  "$self -m" | wc -l )
  if [ "$CHECK_PID_NUMS" -gt 2 ]; then
     zenity --info --text "Notifications already disabled"
     exit 0
  else  
     killall notify-osd 2> /dev/null # ensure we have PID
     notify-send 'All notifications will be muted after this one' 
     sleep 1
     while true 
     do 
        PID=$(pgrep notify-osd)
        [  "x$PID" != "x" ]  && 
        kill -TERM $PID 
        sleep 0.25
     done
  fi
}

unmute()
{
  echo $0
  self=${0##*/}

  MUTE_PID=$(pgrep -f  "$self -m" ) #match self with -m option
  if [ "x$MUTE_PID" != "x"   ];then
     kill -TERM "$MUTE_PID" &&
     sleep 1 && # ensure the previous process exits
     notify-send "UNMUTED"
     exit 0
  else 
     notify-send "NOTIFICATIONS ALREADY UNMUTED"
     exit 0
  fi  
}

print_usage()
{
  cat > /dev/stderr <<EOF
  usage: notify-block.sh [-m|-u]
EOF
exit 1
}
main()
{
  [ $# -eq 0  ] && print_usage

  while getopts "mu" options
  do

     case ${options} in
          m) mute_notifications & ;;
          u) unmute ;;
          \?) print_usage ;;
     esac

  done
}
main "$@"
```

#### .desktop shortcut  template

This is just an example of what I personally use. Replace each `Exec=` line with appropriate path to script in your environment. Of course your `Icon=` will have to be changed as well. Preferably , keep this file in your `~/.local/share/applications` folder

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Notification Blocker
Comment=blocks any on-screen notifications
Terminal=false
Actions=Mute;Unmute
Type=Application
Exec=/home/xieerqi/sergrep/notify-block.sh -m
Icon=/home/xieerqi/Desktop/no-notif2.png

[Desktop Action Mute]
Name=Mute Notifications
Exec=/home/xieerqi/sergrep/notify-block.sh -m
Terminal=false

[Desktop Action Unmute]
Name=Unmute Notifications
Exec=/home/xieerqi/sergrep/notify-block.sh -u
Terminal=false
```

#### Screenshots

[image: image1]

*The shortcut file locked to launcher*

[image]

*Final notification before muting*

Comment: I seem to have problems unmuting it?.. I should i manually kill the process everytime or ?

Comment: No, unmuting option does exactly that, kills the previous process instance. What exactly is the issue that's happening?

Comment: No message,  occur. I can mute, but not unmute by pressing the unmute buttom..

Comment: @Lamda OK, inside the `unmute` function, can you please add `set -x` after the `echo $0` line and run the program in terminal ? It will display certain output. Copy and paste that to paste.ubuntu.com and provide link to that paste in the comments here. Thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/wJUpSdsA

Comment: Very odd, I don't see anything wrong there and it performs as expected , yet notifications don't respawn.  Is the process still listed after you use `-u` option ? Check that with `ps -ef | grep notify-block` .

Comment: It is not listed.

Comment: lamda+ 18407 18340  0 15:46 pts/30   00:00:00 grep --color=auto notify-block

Comment: @Lamda so the script works , it kills its previous instance but on your system notifications don't respawn for some reason. I've asked couple people to test it out just now and it works for them the same as for me. I'm not entirely sure what happens.

Comment: I am at work at the moment, so it could be me that have misunderstood something.. I think I will check it later today when I come home.