# How can I automatically mute an application when not in focus?

Tags: sound, scripts, games, steam

When I'm playing some games like chivalry Medieval Warfare and I switch to another software like Firefox or Desktop the sound of the game still plays.

So, How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: Perhaps you can mute it in Sound Settings, Applications tab.

Comment: The WM_CLASS is `bftag@KubuntuMSW:~$ xprop WM_CLASS
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "UDKGame-Linux", "UDKGame-Linux"`

Comment: @mikewhatever has the right idea - system settings -> sounds seems to use pactl to mute specific app, which is what i used in my script

Comment: This not  a problem my friend, it is  a feature request I think.

Comment: Thank you all for your support, I am gonna try the script in few days,when I'll can use my computer.

Comment: Thank you  to everybody who have helped me, The script works fine and I can now switch without sound game .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### (Automatically) mute sound of a specific application if its window is not in front

I tested the script below on Rhythmbox, doing the job without a single error.

Running the script below in the background will pause the targeted process if its window is not in front (within one second), muting sound if it comes with the application. 
Whenever the window gets in front again, the process is resumed where it was, and sound works again.

If the targeted process/application does *not run at all*, the script switches to a longer period (mode), checking *only once per five seconds* if the targeted application runs or not. This way, the script is extremely low on juice if it has no job to fulfill.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

# ---set the proc to pause when not the active window
wclass = "rhythmbox"
# ---

def get(cmd):
    # just a helper function to not repeat verbose subprocess sections
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

while True:
    # the longer period: application is not running (saving fuel)
    time.sleep(5)
    front1 = ""
    while True:
        # if the application runs, switch to a shorter response time
        time.sleep(1)
        # get the possible pid, get() returns "None" if not running,
        # script then switches back to 5 sec check
        pid = get(["pgrep", wclass])
        if pid:
            front2 = wclass in get([
                "xprop", "-id", get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])
                ])
            # run either kill -stop or kill -cont only if there is
            # a change in the situation
            if front2 != front1:
                if front2 == True:
                    cm = ["kill", "-cont", pid]
                    print("run") # just a test indicator, remove afterwards
                else:
                    cm = ["kill", "-stop", pid]
                    print("stop") # just a test indicator, remove afterwards
                subprocess.Popen(cm)
            front1 = front2
        else:
            break
```

#### How to use

- The script needs `xdotool` to get information on the frontmost window:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install xdotool
  ```
- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `pause_app.py`
- In the head section of the script, set the process name to pause (replace `rhythmbox`). 
  Usually this is the same as the (first section of) the `WM_CLASS`, but in your case, I am having doubts if this should not be `steam` or something else. Run to make sure

  ```
  ps -u <yourname>
  ```

  to make an educated guess, and subsequently

  ```
  kill <pid> 
  (the process id)
  ```

  to check.
- Run the script by the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/pause_app.py
  ```

  and check if all works as expected.
- If all works fine, add to Startup Applications: Dash > Startup Applications > Add. Then add the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/pause_app.py
  ```

#### Note

The script can be easily edited to target multiple applications, but first please see if this is what you need.

#### Alternatively

If you'd prefer to mute the sound *in general* once the targeted window is not in front, replace the command to *pause the application* by the command to *mute (/unmute) sound*. The script then becomes:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

# ---set the proc to pause when not the active window
wclass = "rhythmbox"
# ---

def get(cmd):
    # just a helper function to not repeat verbose subprocess sections
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

while True:
    # the longer period: application is not running (saving fuel)
    time.sleep(5)
    front1 = ""
    while True:
        # if the application runs, switch to a shorter response time
        time.sleep(1)
        # get the possible pid, get() returns "None" if not running,
        # script then switches back to 5 sec check
        pid = get(["pgrep", wclass])
        if pid:
            front2 = wclass in get([
                "xprop", "-id", get(["xdotool", "getactivewindow"])
                ])
            # run either kill -stop or kill -cont only if there is
            # a change in the situation
            if front2 != front1:
                if front2 == True:
                    cm = ["amixer", "-q", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "on"]
                    print("sound") # just a test indicator, remove afterwards
                else:
                    cm = ["amixer", "-q", "-D", "pulse", "sset", "Master", "off"]
                    print("no sound") # just a test indicator, remove afterwards
                subprocess.Popen(cm)
            front1 = front2
        else:
            break
```

Usage is exactly similar to the first script.

Comment: Jacob, it would really be great if you would put a few more comment lines in your scripts then newcomers to python can learn as well from them without needing the script in the solution itself :)

Comment: @Videonauth excellent suggestion, I will edit!

Comment: yeah I'm one of the python new-bes who scour the site for input how certain things are done ;)

Comment: @Videonauth that is a pleasure! will edit tonight, have to get a deadline though at the moment, kind of stressy :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm Thank you so much I'll  try it at home.

Comment: I just tried and it is work perfectly as expected. : D                                           thank you

Comment: @BattlefieldTAG ah, greatgreat. Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 4):

The script bellow relies on all native tools of Ubuntu, `pactl` and `qdbus` to determine active app, automatically mute and unmute as the app gains and focus from user.

The app name is set in `APP_ICON_NAME` variable. You can use `pactl list sink-inputs | grep icon_name` to determine the value you need it to be set. In my case, i tested it with `chromium-browser` .

The script will undergo minor improvements in style and perhaps additional features will be added , but as of right now it's 90% usable and performs it's task properly. It will eventually be posted to github

```
#!/bin/bash

list_sinks()
{
  pactl list sink-inputs | awk '/Sink Input #/{ sub(/#/," ");  printf $3" "} /application.icon_name/{ printf $0"\n" }'
}

get_active_app_icon_name()
{
  qdbus org.ayatana.bamf  /org/ayatana/bamf/matcher org.ayatana.bamf.matcher.ActiveApplication \
      | xargs -I {} qdbus org.ayatana.bamf {} org.ayatana.bamf.view.Icon
}



get_sinks_for_app()
{
  list_sinks | while read line ; do

    if grep -q "$APP_ICON_NAME" <<< "$line"
    then
       awk '{printf $1" "}' <<< "$line"
    fi
 done
}

mute_sinks()
{
   for sink_id in $( get_sinks_for_app  ) ; do
       pactl set-sink-input-mute "$sink_id" 1
   done
}

unmute_sinks()

{
   for sink_id in $( get_sinks_for_app  ) ; do
       pactl set-sink-input-mute "$sink_id" 0
   done
}
main()
{
  local APP_ICON_NAME="chromium-browser"

  while true 
  do

     if [ "$( get_active_app_icon_name )" != "$APP_ICON_NAME" ] ;
     then
          mute_sinks
     else 
         unmute_sinks
     fi

  sleep 0.25  
  done
}


main
```

Comment: Hi Serg, you really need to look into the system load, it adds too much for a continuesly running process.

Comment: @JacobVlijm how much ?

Comment: I get +6 to 7%, but the rule should be imo, if you notice, it's too much.

Comment: @JacobVlijm `htop` reports around 2% for me

Comment: Yeah, that's possible, not sure why and how, but it probably triggers other processes to consume more. We've had this before, I will look it up...

Comment: @JacobVlijm I can try `renice`ing the script from within itself , if that's a good approach

Comment: Got it, it was on this one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/769948/is-there-a-dont-disturb-option-to-temporarily-hide-notifications-like-on-mac/770896#770896 oooops... need to go back to my deadline :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm wait what do you mean ?

Comment: By my deadline? Need to finish a major report on something before tomorrow morning (nothing on AU)

Comment: @JacobVlijm no , i meant what about that question that you've linked ?

Comment: Ah, sorry, instead of using htop, look what happens in the graph when running your script in the linked question.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I don't see any graph there, it's a link to the notification blocking script . . .

Comment: Yeah, but while running that one, run system monitor, showing the graph on cpu. ( we might need to remove the comments if we don't want to be thrown out of the elections :) )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41080/discussion-between-serg-and-jacob-vlijm).

Answer (score 3):

If the game is using the normal sound system from ubuntu, a.k.a. pulse audio, then you go into:

system settings -> sound -> applications

You should see your song playing application there, you can change the volume and even mute it.