# How to in/decrease the volume of a specific application by command?

Tags: command-line, bash, sound, pulseaudio

I want to create a keyboard shortcut to decrease the volume of the application I am currently in. So the first step is to change the volume **of one specific application** by command. So how is this possible?

Edit: I want to have different volumes per application at one time.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/180612/script-to-mute-an-application?rq=1

Comment: Seems to me you just need to use `set-sink-input-volume` instead of `set-sink-input-mute` in that script. See [the `pactl` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/pactl.1.html) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

#### Setting volume from cli

The command:

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master 30%
```

is one I found always working so far. To completely dim:

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master off
```

Switch back on:

```
amixer -q -D pulse sset Master on
```

#### Setting volume per application

Not sure if you want different sound volumes for different applications *at the same time*, or you'd like to set the volume, depending on what application is in front.

If the latter is the case, take a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/786127/72216). It includes a script, dimming sound depending on the active window. Can easily be made to set a specific volume.

To find more information on how to do it *per application at the same time* see the [answers to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180612/script-to-mute-an-application?rq=1), as provided by @muru.

Comment: @Marton your second step should be a different question.