# How can I kill a dbus monitor script when an application exits?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, dbus, monitoring

I am using a simple `dbus-monitor` script for `gnote`. The script starts when `gnote` starts. I modified `Exec=` -line of the `.desktop` file to achieve this.

The problem is that I didn't find any way to kill my script after the application(i.e **gnote**) exits. If the application itself exits there is no point to keep script running in the background as it is not going to fetch any output.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 


OJECT="'org.gnome.Gnote'" 
IFACE="'org.gnome.Gnote.RemoteControl'" 
DPATH="'/org/gnome/Gnote/RemoteControl'" 
echo $IFACE


WATCH1="type='signal',sender=${OJECT},interface=${IFACE},path=${DPATH},member='NoteAdded'" 
WATCH2="type='signal',sender=${OJECT},interface=${IFACE},path=${DPATH},member='NoteSaved'" 
WATCH3="type='signal', sender=${OJECT}, interface=${IFACE}, path=${DPATH}, member='NoteDeleted'"

dbus-monitor ${WATCH2} | 
while read LINE; do
  echo $LINE | grep "note://"
done
```

I tried to modify it like this :

```
dbus-monitor ${WATCH2} | 
while read LINE; do
  echo $LINE | grep "note://"
  if pgrep "gnote" > /dev/null; then
    echo ""
  else
    break;
  fi
done

pid=`pidof -x $(basename $0)`
kill $pid
```

But it didn't work. I also tried using `trap` as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165057/executing-bash-loop-while-command-is-running) but without success.

Comment: Hi Khurshid, did you notice the answer(s)?

Comment: Yes. I did. Sorry for late response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The issue

...is that your dbus- monitor script runs a child- process (`dbus-monitor`) which is not killed with the script, actually making the script "un- killable".

#### What to do

What you need to do is use a wrapper, running gnote + the monitor script, then when `gnote` ends, kill the `dbus-monitor`- script by the command:

```
pkill -P <pid>
```

...where `<pid>` is the pid of your monitor script (I used `pgrep -f /path/to/script`) . This will kill the script *and* its children, terminating it successfully.

I ran into exactly the same issue writing [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/770896/72216).

#### The wrapper

Assuming your monitor script is executable, run `gnote` by the command:

```
'/path/to/monitorscript' & gnote && pkill -P "$( pgrep -f '/path/to/monitorscript )"
```

The easyest is to make it a one- liner script and start the script from your `.desktop` -file

Comment: This is not working for me.  It seems pgrep -f is failing. Also it doesn't work if there are more than one script running. However I made it work by changing it like this: `'/path/to/monitorscript' & gnote && killall "/path/to/monitorscript"`

Comment: '/path/to/monitorscript' & gnote && killall dbus-monitor

Answer (score 1):

Consider having a function in *background* that will poll `pgrep` for `gnote`'s pid, and once PID stop the `dbus-monitor` ( note the use of `-f` flag with `pkill` ). Also , notice how the background function is called - `stop_monitor &`

I've modified your script to include such function. Installed gnote, tested on Ubuntu 16.04 , works as expected.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash 

stop_monitor()
{
    while pgrep "gnote" > /dev/null
    do
       :
    done

    pkill -f "dbus-monitor"
}

OJECT="'org.gnome.Gnote'" 
IFACE="'org.gnome.Gnote.RemoteControl'" 
DPATH="'/org/gnome/Gnote/RemoteControl'" 
echo $IFACE


WATCH1="type='signal',sender=${OJECT},interface=${IFACE},path=${DPATH},member='NoteAdded'" 
WATCH2="type='signal',sender=${OJECT},interface=${IFACE},path=${DPATH},member='NoteSaved'" 
WATCH3="type='signal', sender=${OJECT}, interface=${IFACE}, path=${DPATH}, member='NoteDeleted'"

stop_monitor &

dbus-monitor ${WATCH2} | 
while read LINE; 
do
    echo $LINE | grep "note://"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working. But infinite loop is causing the process to go over 35 MB over time...not sure why. I am using `while sleep 10` which is also working without cpu/memory hog.

Comment: @KhurshidAlam by 35 MB you mean 35 MB of RAM ? or are you redirecting output to file ?  Also, with  the `while` loop in the `stop_monitor` function, consider adding `sleep 0.25` .

Comment: Also, if this answer is working for you, consider marking it as accepted or at least leave an upvote to express that this answer is useful. Again, up to your consideration

Comment: Redirecting?....Yes...only redirecting standard output and error to system log. `exec 1> >(logger -s -t $(basename $0) 2>&1)` and `exec 2> >(logger -s -t $(basename $0))` But it's not that important. I can remove this.

Comment: I like the above method using wrapper. So I have accepted that as an answer.  But this one works too. Thanks.