# What is the command to kill/close notifications?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, notification, notify-osd, notify-send

By default, I have to wait for a few seconds for the notifications to fade off.

I'd like to know the command to kill them immediately, so I can bind it to a shortcut key. (Super+N seems good right now.)

PS: I tried installing notify-osd, but the terminal says it couldn't find the package notifyosdconfig.

Comment: To permanently suppress only specific notifications etc: http://askubuntu.com/a/770896/72216

Comment: Thanks to Jacob Vlijm. Another question he referenced gave me the exact command I wanted: `pkill notify-osd`

Comment: @VũKarobettaTrọngNghĩa you're welcome. As often, a dupe or not, it is a good question. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can use notify-osd itself. However, `notifyosdconfig` need to be installed separately. Use the ppa `nilarimogard/webupd8` and install `notifyosdconfig`.