# Quick way to temporarily disable notifications in Plasma/KDE/Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 19.04, notification, plasma

I'd like to be able to quickly disable and re-enable notifications in the KDE Plasma desktop (Kubuntu 19.04); essentially, a "focus" mode.

Previous (4+ years old) answers - [Is it possible to temporarily disable notifications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185078/is-it-possible-to-temporarily-disable-notifications) - don't seem to apply, as the `notify-osd`  process is not visible in my system process monitor.

Anyone have a **simple** method? I'm sure I could write a script or some such, but it seems like a feature that should be included in Kubuntu, and I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

> I'd like to be able to quickly disable and re-enable notifications in
>   the KDE Plasma desktop (Kubuntu 19.04)

I don't know if this is quick enough but ...

Kubuntu 18.10+ has [kubuntu-notification-helper](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/cosmic/+package/kubuntu-notification-helper):

> Kubuntu Notification Helper is a daemon that presents various
>   notifications to the user. It uses the KDE Daemon system as a base and
>   presents the notifications using the KDE Notification system. It also
>   includes a System Settings module for configuring the daemon. Kubuntu
>   Notification Helper is lightweight and fully integrated with KDE.
>
> Current features include:
>     - Notifications for Apport crashes.
>     - Notifications for upgrade information, when available.
>     - Notifications for the availability restrictively-licensed packages.
>     - Notifications for when upgrades require a reboot to complete.
>     - All notifications can be hidden temporarily or permanently.

You can access this GUI via a terminal by running

```
kcmshell5 kcm_notificationhelper
```

The image below is from Kubuntu 19.04 with Plasma 5.16.2 (which is provided by the [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports).)

**GUI for managing certain notifications**

[image: GUI for managing certain notifications]

Alternatively, open *System Settings* and search for "Other notifications" to get the same GUI.

Comment: I know of this GUI, but it doesn't seem to offer the ability to: 

A: Turn off notifications for specific applications (like Slack or Spotify, for example)
B: Turn off all notifications temporarily. 

At least that I can see. Am I missing something?